# Construct axis if you have drawn $y=x^2$ plot

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, conic-sections, geometric-construction

In the coordinate plane $xOy$ you have drawn parabola $y=x^2$. Now delete the coordinate axes. Using a straightedge and a compass reconstruct coordinate axes.

Comment: Ummm... draw a line tangent to the apex.  Then draw a line perpendicular to that line, through the apex.

Comment: Yes, but how to find the apex without the axes?

Comment: I like the wikipedia entry for "parabola".  Have you learned how to find the locus and directrix for a given parabola?

Comment: Do you mean "ruler"  or "straightedge."  A ruler allows us to measure lengths and makes the problem easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Draw any two parallel chords. Their midpoints determine a line parallel to the axis.

[image]

Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you very much, I just finished construction!
Let p be the red line form above, all I need is to draw perpendicular line to it. 
Midpoint of that line lies on $y$ axis. Then I will draw $y$ axis, and after that $x$ axis.

I think this is the right solution.

Comment: @DjoleSt: Congratulations! That is correct. ... I suggest you write your comment into an answer so that we can upvote your success. You could/should also accept it.

Comment: Good old Archimedes!